# Proof by induction that $B\cup (\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i)=\bigcap_{i=1}^n (B\cup A_i)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

[image: induction proof]

$\displaystyle B\cup (\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i)=\bigcap_{i=1}^n (B\cup A_i)$

I was able to prove this without using induction, however I am supposed to prove it using induction. How should I go about doing so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The base case $n=1$ holds since $B\cup\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^1A_i\right)=B\cup A_1$ and $\bigcap_{i=1}^1(B\cup A_i)=B\cup A_1$.

Now, suppose inductively that $B\cup\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^nA_i\right)=\bigcap_{i=1}^n(B\cup A_i)$. Then 
\begin{align*}
B\cup\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n+1}A_i\right)
&= B\cup \left[\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^nA_i\right)\cap A_{n+1}\right] \\
&= \left[B\cup\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^nA_i\right) \right]\cap\left(B\cap A_{n+1}\right) \\
&=?
\end{align*}
can you finish the inductive step by applying the inductive hypothesis?

Comment: After re-reading the notes about induction, I'm having a hard time applying the inductive hypothesis. Would you be so kind to elaborate?

Comment: I say suppose inductively that $B\cup\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i\right)=\bigcap_{i=1}^n\left(B\cup A_i\right)$ and the left side of this equality appears in our equation for $B\cup\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n+1}A_i\right)$. Replace this with the right-hand side and simplify the result.

Comment: So let me get this right, it would be:

[B∪(⋂ i=1 n A_i )]∩(B∩A_n+1 ) = B∪A_1

Answer (score 0):

Induction on $n$. The base case is $n=1$ is trivial, and the case $n=2$ is required for the induction step as well. Now assume that the claim holds for $n=k$. For $n=k+1$, write the LHS and RHS out, and split the intersection/union to the first $n$ terms and the last one. That will bring you back to the case $n=2$, and allow you to establish the induction step.