# Induction of $A_i$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

The base case $n=1$:

$B\cup\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^1A_i\right)=B\cup A_1$

and

$\bigcap_{i=1}^1(B\cup A_i)=B\cup A_1$.

Now, suppose inductively that $B\cup\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^nA_i\right)=\bigcap_{i=1}^n(B\cup A_i)$. Then 
\begin{align*}
B\cup\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n+1}A_i\right)
&= B\cup \left[\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^nA_i\right)\cap A_{n+1}\right] \\
&= \left[B\cup\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^nA_i\right) \right]\cap\left(B\cap A_{n+1}\right) \\
\end{align*}

I am stuck at this point of the induction process, could someone please assist me.

Comment: Please do not plagiarize: At least link back to the [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/670334/proof-by-induction-set-theory/670342#670342) that you've copied here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use your induction hypothesis $B\cup\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i\right)=\bigcap_{i=1}^n (B\cup A_i)$. You can then write
\begin{align}
&=\left[ B\cup\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i\right) \right] \cap (B\cup A_{n+1})\\
&=\left[\bigcap_{i=1}^n (B\cup A_i)\right]\cap(B\cup A_{n+1})\\
&=\bigcap_{i=1}^{n+1} (B\cup A_i),
\end{align}

which gives you the desired result.

Comment: Makes sense! How would you go about doing it without induction though. Would you just provide a specific example?

Comment: @petrov No, one example would not be enough -- there would still be infinitely many cases that you did not prove. If you were to show it without induction, you should show that the two set are subsets of each other. Ie. if $x\in B\cup \left( \bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i\right)$ then $x\in \bigcap_{i=1}^n \left(B\cup A_i\right)$.

Answer (score 1):

Last term in the bracket will be BUAn+1. Thus the relation holds true for n+1 also.